# React Native Expo Vertical Scoll

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

trying to implement a vertical scroll view on the post section but only works if I touch the section with "what would you like to do " first is there a way to make the scroll bar visible? or just make it work in general??

const DashBoard = () => {
return (

```
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={tw` flex-1`}
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
    >

        <LoggedInLayout>
            <ScrollView
                style={tw`px-6`}
                contentContainerStyle={tw.style(` `, {
                    flexGrow: 1
                })}
            >

                <View
                    style={apptw`flex-row justify-between px-4 py-5`}
                >
                    <View>
                        <AppText>
                            Hi User
                        </AppText>
                    </View>

                    <View>
                        <AppText>
                            Share Profile
                        </AppText>
                    </View>

                </View>

                <View
                    style={apptw`bg-white pt-5  rounded-full`}
                >
                    <View>
                        <AppText
                            style={apptw`text-center`}
                        >
                            What would you like to do?
                        </AppText>
                    </View>

                    <View
                        style={{
                            borderBlockColor: "gray",
                            borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth
                        }}
                    />

                    <ScrollView
                        style={apptw`flex-row  mx-10 rounded-full`}
                        horizontal={true}
                        contentContainerStyle={tw.style(`justify-between`, {
                            flexGrow: 1,
                        })}
                    >
                        <AppButtonWIcon
                            text="New Post"
                            buttonStyle={apptw`w-[30] bg-white mr-4 rounded-full`}
                            textStyle={apptw`text-[3] text-black  mx-auto`}
                            icon={
                                <MaterialIcons
                                    name="post-add"
                                    size={20}
                                    style={tw`mx-auto`}
                                    color="#0413BB"
                                />
                            }
                        />


                        <AppButtonWIcon
                            text="New Journal"
                            buttonStyle={apptw`w-[30] bg-white mr-4 rounded-full`}
                            textStyle={apptw`text-[3] text-black  mx-auto`}
                            icon={

                                <FontAwesome name="pencil-square"
                                    size={20}
                                    style={tw`mx-auto`}
                                    color="#0413BB"
                                />

                            }
                        />

                        <AppButtonWIcon
                            text="Seek Help"
                            buttonStyle={apptw`w-[30] bg-white mr-4 rounded-full`}
                            textStyle={apptw`text-[3] text-black  mx-auto`}
                            icon={

                                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                                    name="handshake"
                                    size={20}
                                    style={tw`mx-auto`}
                                    color="#0413BB"
                                />

                            }
                        />


                        <AppButtonWIcon
                            text="View Friends"
                            buttonStyle={apptw`w-[30] bg-white mr-4 rounded-full`}
                            textStyle={apptw`text-[3] text-black  mx-auto`}
                            icon={

                                <Ionicons
                                    name="people-sharp"
                                    size={20}
                                    style={tw`mx-auto`}
                                    color="#0413BB"
                                />



                            }
                        />

                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
                <View
                    style={apptw`mt-5 pb-5`}
                >
                    <AppText
                        style={apptw`text-bold text-2xl `}
                    >
                        Your Posts
                    </AppText>

                    <View
                        style={apptw`bg-primary w-1/2 h-1 rounded-full`}
                    />
                </View>

                {/* Posts */}

                <ScrollView >
                    <PostsDisplay
                        content="hggg"
                        date="28-aug-23"
                        image="image"
                        name="mads"
                    />


                    <PostsDisplay
                        content="hggg"
                        date="28-aug-23"
                        image="image"
                        name="mads"
                    />


                    <PostsDisplay
                        content="hggg"
                        date="28-aug-23"
                        image="image"
                        name="mads"
                    />


                </ScrollView>


            </ScrollView>
        </LoggedInLayout>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

)
```

}

here is the post-display component

```
 return (
    <View style={apptw`bg-white rounded-b-xl rounded-t-md mb-5 flex`}>
        <View style={apptw`flex-row justify-between p-5 rounded-t-md`}>
            <AppText>{props.image}</AppText>
            <AppText>{props.name}</AppText>
            <AppText>{props.date}</AppText>
        </View>

        <View style={apptw`bg-specpurple w-full p-5 rounded-b-xl overflow-y-scroll max-h-48`}>
            <AppText style={apptw`text-center`}>{props.content}</AppText>
        </View>
    </View>

)
```

"expo": "~49.0.7",
"react-native": "0.72.4",

Answer (score 0):

You can use showsVerticalScrollIndicator to set the visibility of vertical scroll bar .You can read about showsVerticalScrollIndicator [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#showsverticalscrollindicator)